# Adding Images to an ASP.net website table database column

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, vb.net

I'm currently working on a project for school to create an e-commerce website, part of my task is to use a database to display products on a web form, I've got my database and I've got my table data but I just can't get images to work from here, what I am wanting is to add a local image I have in my website folder to my ImageURL column in my database, and from here I would be able to display this image in a gridview using a textfield, I've added a link to the base code I've got for the table and my question is how do I get to add an image from here? I've tried a few solutions already just to get errors thrown back at me! any help would be great appreciated.

http://prntscr.com/hdl1z8

This is an example database we was given to use for some practical lessons, this works fine but when I replicate this code into my own table, and then try to display the image linked using a gridview the website diplays nothing and it gives no errors.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Book] ([BookID], [Title], [Author], [CategoryId], [Price], [ImageURL]) VALUES (N'P01', N'Abs Beginner', N'Smith', 1, CAST(24.9900 AS Money), N'~/Images/P01.jpg')
```

This is what it would look like using my images and my table data, when I try to execute it using my own database I get an error from incorrect syntax, and the table data is not updated.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Shoes] ([ShoeID], [Name], [Brand], [CategoryID], [Price], [ImageURL]) VALUES (N'S01', N'Kids 1    ', NULL, 1, CAST(10.9900 AS Money), N'~/Images/S01.jpg')
```

Comment: We don't want a link to the base code. We want to you to post the relevant (and ONLY the relevant) code right here in your question, formatted so that we can read it easily. If you've tried something then show us.  Post the code that you think should work and explain exactly how it's behaviour differs from your expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited my post with the information I think is correct now.

I've also added some additional information hope this provides more insight to my issues.

Comment: You said: "I get an error from incorrect syntax" what is the error? And for what you said: "the website diplays nothing and it gives no errors" can you write click on Chrome, press Inspect Element and post a screenshot of the html code?

Comment: The error I get from Visual is simply a "Syntax Error 8001" it displays no other error information, the website with the gridview displayed in the HTML the row where the image should be displayed is in there as Table Data however it is empty and contains no other code.